# Refine simple image edge quickly

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm looking to copy images from one program into Photoshop, re-size and apply stroke & color overlay. When I re-size the image the edges are become very jagged. Like so:
[image]

Is there a way to smooth these edges quickly? I have to do this to around 4,500 images. Currently i'm manually cutting away the jagged edges but it's incredibly time consuming.

Thanks all.

Comment: Could you post an image of the original before scaling? If your edges are anti-aliased it's a lot easier to get a good result than if the edges are sharp.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this. Here're my shapes: original and pushed up to 500%

[image]

1. Load layer as a selection (top Photoshop menu `Select > Load Selection > Channel: Layer Transparency`):

   [image]
2. Using `Select > Select And Mask` I'd try to find the values that give me the result I like: it's usually some feather, then contrast, a bit of smoothing and shrinking edges a bit. Outputting the result to a new selection.

   [image]
3. Now I have a sharp selection. Next I just create a new layer, fill it with foreground color (`Edit > Fill`), remove selection, apply overlay and stroke:

   [image]
4. Then I record all these steps as an Action and can assign it to a hotkey or run it on a folder of files using `File > Automate > Batch...`

   [image]

You're going to lose some details: like sharp corner and smoothness of circles, but you can bend the result to be more sharp or more smooth depending on your needs using different settings for `Select and Mask` or expanding/contracting your original selection.